# Define polynomial function

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I define a function - say, `def polyToString(poly)` - to return a string containing the polynomial `poly` in standard form?

For example: the polynomial represented by `[-1, 2, -3, 4, -5]` would be returned as:

```
"-5x**4 + 4x**3 -3x**2 + 2x**1 - 1x**0"
```

```
def polyToString(poly):
    standard_form=''
    n=len(poly) - 1
    while n >=0:
        if poly[n]>=0:
            if n==len(poly)-1: 
                standard_form= standard_form + '   '+ str(poly[n]) + 'x**%d'%n 
            else:
                standard_form= standard_form + ' + '+str(poly[n]) + 'x**%d'%n
        else:
            standard_form= standard_form + ' - ' + str(abs(poly[n])) + 'x**' + str(n)
        n=n-1
    return standard_form
```

Comment: def polyToString(poly):
    standard_form=''
    n=len(poly) - 1
    while n >=0:
        if poly[n]>=0:
            if n==len(poly)-1: #no '+' sign in the front of the first item
                standard_form= standard_form + '   '+ str(poly[n]) + 'x**%d'%n 
            else:
                standard_form= standard_form + ' + '+str(poly[n]) + 'x**%d'%n
        else:
            standard_form= standard_form + ' - ' + str(abs(poly[n])) + 'x**' + str(n)
        n=n-1
    return standard_form

Comment: @user1822707 please, put that in the question text.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I don't know how to edit this.

Comment: Your code seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Why so difficult ?

```
def poly_to_str(coefs):
    return ''.join(['{:+d}x**{:d}'.format(a,n) for n, a in enumerate(coefs)][::-1])
```

**Explanation**

- `enumerate(coefs)` gives us `n`,`a` which are `ax**n` for std form of
  member
- `'{:+d}x**{:d}'.format(a,n)` formats every member
- `{:+d}` says to print decimal number with sign
- `[..][::-1]` reverses array of members
- `''.join(..)` joins them into one string

**Example**

`print poly_to_str([-1, 2, -3, 4, -5])`

outputs

`-5x**4+4x**3-3x**2+2x**1-1x**0`

Answer (score 0):

Something which might be a little bit easier for a beginner to read.

```
def poly2str(coefs):
    retstr=""
    for i in range(len(coefs)):
        if coefs[i] < 0:
            retstr += " -" + str(abs(coefs[i])) + "x**" + str(len(coefs) - i) + " "
        else:
            retstr += "+ " + str(abs(coefs[i])) + "x**" + str(len(coefs) - i) + " "

    return retstr
```